# use full text search to search incomplete words in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am making a library management system.
I have a problem in the search for a book from mysql database.

For searching data in mysql we use full text search .

But it only works if a full  word is given. If user enters an incomplete word instead of the actual word , is there any function to search.

ex : if book name is calculus,
     if user types calc , then also the books should come

Comment: What's your code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using fulltext search with [boolean mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html), which allows a few extra operators. You will be interested in the truncation operator (`*`):

> The asterisk serves as the truncation (or wildcard) operator. Unlike
>   the other operators, it is appended to the word to be affected. Words
>   match if they begin with the word preceding the * operator.
>
> If a word is specified with the truncation operator, it is not
>   stripped from a boolean query, even if it is too short or a stopword.
>   Whether a word is too short is determined from the
>   innodb_ft_min_token_size setting for InnoDB tables, or ft_min_word_len
>   for MyISAM tables. These options are not applicable to FULLTEXT
>   indexes that use the ngram parser.
>
> The wildcarded word is considered as a prefix that must be present at
>   the start of one or more words. If the minimum word length is 4, a
>   search for '+word +the*' could return fewer rows than a search for
>   '+word +the', because the second query ignores the too-short search
>   term the.

Pls note, that you cannot **start** an expression with the `*` operator, so the results cannot include a book, which title **contains** 'calc', only which title **starts** with 'calc'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LIKE operator with the "%" wildcard

```
With LIKE you can use the following two wildcard characters in the pattern:

% matches any number of characters, even zero characters.
```

for example

```
SELECT * FROM <Table> where book like "%calc%";
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html